# Python unicode date parsing

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, unicode, utf-8

Here is a extract of my code in Python 2.7:

```
reg = ...#some format to find a date like (\d\d)[/ ](\d\d)|(\w{1,20})[/ ](\d\d\d\d)
pattern = re.compile(reg,re.DOTALL)
try:
    dates = pattern.findall(text)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print 'CANNOT ENCODE'
```

I'm trying to parse a text through regex to find dates, but every time it finds a not standard character it throws the exception.

Since i wanted to parse chinese dates as well (many in the format dd/simbol/yyyy), i have to find a workaround. How can i parse those as well? If i transform the string in utf-8, don't i lose my pattern in regex?

Second question: for this pourpose, does it exist a dictionary with (chineseSimbol) : (month) or (chineseSimbol) : (day)?

EDIT:
So here is an example of what i'm trying to achieve:

Imput: stringstring 14 十一月 2014 stringstring

Desired Output: 14 11 2014

Up to now, i have parsed the whole text with the above code to find a date. But everytime it find a chinese symbol, it get stuck with this error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2794-2802: ordinal not in range(128).

So what i want to do is to get the 十一月 symbol and confront it into a dictionary to get the number of the month as answer. Is this possible? Here i'm confused with the encodings, how to parse it, etc.

Thanks for any help and any sample to how to get this done

Comment: Sure you can't just use dateutil.parser?

Comment: Can you add sample string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to be a little more specific.  Here's an example that works.  If it doesn't help you, update your question with a similar small example with version of Python, desired output, actual output and any tracebacks of error messages.

```
#!python3
#coding:utf8
import re
s = '今天是2014年5月20日。明天是2014年5月21日。'
print(re.findall(r'(\d+)年(\d+)月(\d+)日',s))
```

Output:

```
[('2014', '5', '20'), ('2014', '5', '21')]
```

Also, Python 2.X version:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import re
s = u'今天是2014年5月20日。明天是2014年5月21日。'
print re.findall(ur'(\d+)年(\w+?)月(\w+?)日',s)
```

Output:

```
[(u'2014', u'5', u'20'), (u'2014', u'5', u'21')]
```

Example of parsing some Chinese characters as well:

```
#!python3
#coding:utf8
import re
s = '今天是2014年五月二十日。明天是2014年五月二十一日。'
print(re.findall(r'(\d+)年(.*?)月(.*?)日',s))
```

Output:

```
[('2014', '五', '二十'), ('2014', '五', '二十一')]
```

And Python 2.X:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import re
s = u'今天是2014年五月二十日。明天是2014年五月二十一日。'
print(re.findall(ur'(\d+)年(\w+?)月(\w+?)日',s,re.UNICODE))
```

Output isn't as nice as Python 3.X, but it does get the right characters:

```
[(u'2014', u'\u4e94', u'\u4e8c\u5341'), (u'2014', u'\u4e94', u'\u4e8c\u5341\u4e00')]
```

Comment: Ok, i understand what are you saying. But what about if i want to read the symbols 年,月 and other months symbols through regex? Would i get them with just one (\w) or would i need (\w\w\w\w) since it is encoded?

Comment: Chinese makes it difficult because there are no word boundaries.  The characters are not encoded if you use a Unicode string.  Edit your question and add some example inputs and desired outputs.  I added an example that shows you can parse the characters as well.